Mapbox GL JS is stuck in panning mode
I have a Mapbox GL JS app that loads a 3D model using Threebox. I should be able to select the object but the map is stuck in the panning state with the open hand cursor. If I refresh the page a few times eventually it changes to a standard cursor and allows me to select a 3D object. Is there a way to tell Mapbox to be in the select state by default?
This is my Mapbox initiation script:
mapRef.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/ua-wc/clrdr2ek800az01r20l5tbala/draft',
        center: origin,
        zoom: 18.0,
        maxZoom: 24,
        pitch: 12.97,
        bearing: -39.44,
        antialias: true,
    });

I can see that there are MapOptions for disabling the panning and rotating, but I don't want to disable it. I just need to be able to select the 3D objects. I know it is possible because if I refresh a few times, eventually it allows me to select.
It is possible that this is a Threebox issue and the objects are not interactable for some reason. It seems to work on localhost and not when deployed.
